# How can I access resource use in Windows Bash

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to find out whether wsl/lxss is useful as a development environment, and one of the things that I need is getting resource use details of my programs.

However, what ever I try, Windows does not seem to properly report resource use:

```
~$ sudo ps axo pid,comm,size,rss,%cpu,%mem
  PID COMMAND          SIZE   RSS %CPU %MEM
    1 init                0     0  0.0  0.0
20654 bash                0     0  0.0  0.0
23785 bash                0     0  0.0  0.0
27560 bash                0     0  0.0  0.0
29868 sudo                0     0  0.0  0.0
29869 apt                 0     0  0.0  0.0
31299 dpkg                0     0  0.0  0.0
31351 ca-certificates     0     0  0.0  0.0
31380 ca-certificates     0     0  0.0  0.0
31381 java                0     0  0.0  0.0
31969 sudo                0     0  0.0  0.0
31978 ca-ce <defunct>     0     0  0.0  0.0
31979 ps                  0     0  0.0  0.0
```

(I was actually installing openjdk-7-jre-headless at that moment, so there should have been something more visible)

or

```
~$ sudo htop

  1  [||||||||||||||||||||||||||                    50.2%]     Tasks: 6, 0 thr; 1 running
  2  [|||||||||||||||||||||||||||                   51.0%]     Load average: 0.52 0.58 0.59
  3  [|||||||||||||||||||||||||||                   50.7%]     Uptime: 1 day, 04:09:15
  4  [|||||||||||||||||||||||||||                   51.2%]
  Mem[||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||      4768/7879MB]
  Swp[|                                       156/21539MB]

  PID USER      PRI  NI  VIRT   RES   SHR S CPU% MEM%   TIME+  Command
  278 root       20   0     0     0     0 R  0.0  0.0  0:00.03 htop
    1 root       20   0     0     0     0 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.03 /init
20654 edward     20   0     0     0     0 S  0.0  0.0  0:55.46 /bin/bash
23785 edward     20   0     0     0     0 S  0.0  0.0  0:13.41 /bin/bash
27560 edward     20   0     0     0     0 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.11 /bin/bash
  277 root       20   0     0     0     0 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.03 sudo htop
```

(Install was over at that time, Windows was reporting 6% CPU load)

Am I doing something wrong, or are the system calls simply not yet implemented?

Comment: Note to self: `cat /proc/<id>/stat` seems to be reporting some correct values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Process stats should now be much more accurately reported on Bash/WSL in Insider builds and/or in the Windows 10 Creators Update.

Comment: No creator's update for me yet ( :( ), but from your answer I take that it was simply not yet fully implemented - It's Beta after all. Thank you for the answer though! Linking.. your blog post for completeness https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2017/04/11/windows-10-creators-update-whats-new-in-bashwsl-windows-console/ (PS. Whoever did `INOTIFY` is my hero!)